# Many Relations Between 2 tables - Code First

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

I am building a relationship between 2 tables (code first [entity framework]). But I have the following issue:

[image: Actual Relation Between Employees-Projects]

The table Employees saves the employees with different positions (engineers, technicians, salesmen, etc).

In the table project, **I have 3 relations with the table employees**:

1. **Manager** = Employee with the engineer position
2. **Technician** = Employee with the technician position
3. **Saleman** (EmployeeId) = Employee with the saleman position

Is it possible to create more than one relationship between two tables with EntityFrameWork or do I need to do this (i'm not sure about this).

[image: New Relation Between Employees-Projects]

However, I going to create a table for the positions related with Employees.

Comment: This might be a good read https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070166/2310830

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't see any code first. Pls show what you have done so far.

Comment: i'am building the data base using entity framework . I know to how build a foreign key between tables (1 -1 )  but how you see i have 3 relations in the same tables (the second image). Is recomendable build a 3 relations between 2 tables or make that secundary tables? the question is more related with the normal forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3 Fk in your project table... You can set 3 Fk with fluent api...

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<product>()
            .HasOne<employees>(s => s.Eng)
            .WithMany(g => g.progectEng)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ProjectEngFK);

modelBuilder.Entity<product>()
            .HasOne<employees>(s => s.Tech)
            .WithMany(g => g.progectTech)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ProjectTechFK);
```